# How to show 3D image in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, object, android-jetpack-compose

Lets suppose I have a .psd file or .obj file, I want to show a 3D image in android application, In which I want that user can see that 3D model in app, like user can rotate left right, up-down, or diagonally, I tried to find library but didn't find one.

[![Reference for the thing I am looking for],(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLHHh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLHHh.png)

Thanks in advance.

I tried looking for dependencies, or open source projects, but didn't found expected solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of content you are showing.

If it's a 3D object, and the end result is something akin to SketchFab's model viewer, then you need to write your own renderer which outputs to an framebuffer which can be drawn to an image using `ImageView` or `AppCompatImageView`. The rotation input would be calculated based on drag.

If it's a 2D spritesheet of images taken at different angles of product, then you can just implement an invisible slider or sorts, and depending on how much the slider is dragged, calculate that offset and then show from the spritesheet the appropriate image accordingly.